# How to combine bit fields in Tcl to generate a single 64 bit value?

Tags: tcl

We pass separate paramters into a function that must be combined into a 64 bit value. Thereafter the upper 32 bits and lower 32 bits are written into different addresses in the system. The parameters that are passed in could even exist across the 32 bit boundary e.g across bits 30 to 40, this makes the problem a bit more tricky.

Example,

```
value1 across bits 0 to 13
value2 across bits 23 to 24
value3 across bits 25 to 25
value4 across bits 26 to 40
value5 across bits 41 to 50
value6 across bits 51 to 54
the remaining bits 54 to 63 are unused in this case
```

Provided the value1 to value6 have been passed into a proc in Tcl, how would one go about assembling them into a 64 bit value and then store the upper and lower 32 bits of this 64 bit value into separate variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are all in the range of the field they are to be inserted into, you can just shift them and OR-them together.

```
set value 0
set value [expr {$value | ($value1 << 0)}]
set value [expr {$value | ($value2 << 23)}]
set value [expr {$value | ($value3 << 25)}]
set value [expr {$value | ($value4 << 26)}]
set value [expr {$value | ($value5 << 41)}]
set value [expr {$value | ($value6 << 51)}]
```

If they're not necessarily in range, you need to mask off the out-of-range bits before shifting.

Note that you need *no* special action for going across byte or word boundaries. If you want a bit field that's thousands of places wide, you can have it. (Tcl's integers are generally “as wide as they need to be” and have no technical upper bound until you run into memory management issues.)

Comment: It's possible to use binary strings too, and `format` and `scan`, but the format specifiers are rather long…

Comment: How do you recommend the 64 bit value is then split into two 32 bit values? Same bit shifting can be done I guess, although I am not sure how right shifts would work in tcl since we could end up in needing sign extension in that case.

Comment: The method in a previous question you answered can be used to split the 64 bit value into two 32 bit values and store each of the two in different variable. I am not sure if a "better" i.e more efficient method, exists from programming perspective